# Multiple tag search with Firebase using Swift

Tags: swift, search, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tags

I'm trying to understand how to retrieve data from a Firebase database based on multiple tags. Let's consider the following data structure:

```
{
    "posts":{
        "post1":{
            "title":"First post",
            "description":"that's a nice post",
            "tag": ["tag1","tag2","tag3"]
        },
        "post2":{
             "title":"Second post",
             "description":"the best post",
             "tag": ["tag4","tag5","tag6"]
        },
        "post3":{
            "title":"Third post",
            "description":"cool post",
            "tag": ["tag5","tag80","tag90"]
        }
    }
}
```

Each post has a title, description and an arbitrary size array of tags.

My goal is to show the user only the posts having specific tags. For example I may search for tag1 and tag4, then I want to show post1 and post2 to the user. Or search for tag1 and tag5, then all the three posts must be shown.

Tags in each post are not predefine keywords, they could be any possible word because could also be the case that a user set these tags. So could be that I search for tag100 but nothing is in the database.

I've seen couple of similar posts but I couldn't adapt any of them to this case. Can you give me some hints about the best strategy to handle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a separate structure for "tags", something like this:

```
{
    "posts":{
        "post1":{
            "title":"First post",
            "description":"that's a nice post",
            "tag": ["tag1","tag2","tag100"]
        },
        "post2":{
             "title":"Second post",
             "description":"the best post",
             "tag": ["tag2","tag3","tag100"]
        }
        // more posts...
    },
    "tags":{
        "tag1": ["post1"],
        "tag2": ["post1","post2"],
        "tag3": ["post2"],
        "tag100": ["post1","post2"]
    }
}
```

This way, every time you add a post, you can take tags from that new post and check if they exist in the "tags" structure. If the tag DOES exist already, just push the post onto the end of the array. If the tag DOES NOT exist, create that tag property and add that post in an array as the value.

When you look for posts with any searched tag in the future, you just need to go into the "tags" structure, find any arrays with the searched tag names, use those post titles to get specific posts, and you're on your way.

Note: To add values to the Tag arrays (both in the `"posts"` and `"tags"` structures), you should probably use the `.push()` functionality described in the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data).

Hopefully this helps!